# Google Charts didn't work on IE11

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

Charts didn't work on IE 11. I put meta tag into html file but nothing happens:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

same with:

```
<meta http-equiv= x-ua-compatible content= ie=edge chrome=1>
```

IE11 shows blank page but on Development mode always is

```
Document Mode = 5
```

if I change this parameter to edge then fine. But I imagine meta tags should be Edge??

Answer (score 0):

Try using the more recent URL http://chart.googleapis.com/chart instead of http://chart.apis.google.com/chart